# "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name " after moving database

Tags: sql-server, connection

I moved a database from a hosted `SQL Server 2008` to `SQL Server 2012` on a dedicated server.
I created the database, and copied a table using the `Import/Export` Wizard. And I changed the connection string in the application to point to the new database.

The application seems to be able to connect, but when I do a select or insert  I get the error :

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name '...' ".

When I put the same connection string in the `SQL Management Studio` it connects and works fine.
What could cause this???

Comment: Queries will work only if I specify the table name as  [dbanme].[owner].[tablename]

Comment: If it works when you query using three-part naming (`Database.Schema.Table`) then it's most likely that you've connected to a different database, and/or the default schema for your user is different on the 2012 server. You can specify the correct database name in your connection string, and you [should always specify the schema name](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you may check web.config that if it doesn't contain more than one connection string or you have to make connection by using VS interface then you can easily test connection and this automatically writes connection you web.config